# Opening a heap dump in the .heapdump file format

Tags: java, heap-dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer

This is probably embarrassingly easy but please bear with me.

I have to analyze a heap dump, and have received files in the `.heapdump` format, while I expected `.hprof` files.

The Eclipse memory analyzer refuses to open `.heapdump` files, and I'm not sure which tool I should use, or which transformation to apply in order to get them to work with mat.

Unfortunately, the results of my searches on the matter so far are polluted with basic tutorials, i.e. "how to open a .heapdump file" gets me results on "how to analyze a heap dump" essentially.

**Edit from comments below**

I have tried a few suggestions (thanks all), but none of the below worked:

- Open with VisualVM → does not allow opening the file
- Open with JHat → complains about the magic number (clearly expects another binary format, likely `hprof`)
- Open with the Chrome developer tools → does not support the `.heapdump` format and will not open the file either

Comment: Have you tried with VisualVM ?

Comment: @karelss no, but thanks for the hint, will take a look.

Comment: @karelss doesn't look like it either unfortunately. VisualVM only seems to accept `.hprof` files, even if the modal for opening heap dumps displays both `.hprof` and `.*` entries (which is confusing).

Comment: that's look like a problem for jhat http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html

Comment: Can be the heapdump corrupt in some way?, I mean, how the extract this heapdump?

Comment: @karelss thanks for the link, I'll have a look. I don't think the files are corrupted in any way, I believe the tools I've tried so far are just not made to open files with that extension, hence the question :)

Comment: @karelss and nope, jhat doesn't like the `.heapdump` format either. Complains about "unrecognized magic number" - essentially meaning that the files are not in the expected binary format I guess. But thanks for broadening my horizon with the tools you mentioned :)

Comment: Maybe `.heapdump` is created by `NodeJS` process. If yes, the file should be able to open in `Profile` tab of Chrome’s DevTools.

Comment: @beckyang thanks for the tip, will take a look shortly.

Comment: @beckyang unfortunately this is a nope too: `Can't load file. Only files with extensions '.cpuprofile', '.heapsnapshot', '.heaptimeline', '.heapprofile' can be loaded.`

Comment: @Mena thank you for post this doubt, i'm also eager to know how open this files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the cost of making this look self-serving and suspiciously convenient, I am now able to answer my own question.

The `.heapdump` file format can be opened by an IBM tool called **Heap Analyzer**, which is publicly available on [developerWorks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=4544bafe-c7a2-455f-9d43-eb866ea60091) at the time of writing.

---

**Disclaimer**

I am employed by IBM at the time of writing.